# Get the closest swatch from an PNG color set

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, swatches, google-material-design

So I have a set of PNG colors provided to me.

But as agreed to our design guidelines, we shall use the [Material colors](https://material.google.com/style/color.html) provided by Google.

So if example that there exists a "lime" color from the PNG colors provided to me, I want to select the **closest "lime" color** to it from the provided Material palette swatches for Illustrator (maybe through the eye dropper tool or something else).

Is there a way? Manual selection of a similar color is a tiresome process, and I also color-blindness tendencies, so I have somewhat difficulties in comparing the provided PNG colors to the Material palette.

Answer (score 1):

First load the Material Design color swatches in to Illustrator using the Swatches panel. You can then use the Recolor Artwork tool (**Edit → Edit Colors → Recolor Artwork...**) to limit colors to that color palette.

Simply select all your artwork, open the Recolor Artwork tool and select the Material Palette from the "Limit to Library" button. Make sure you change the colorization method to "Exact" by clicking the dropdown next to any of the "New" color squares:

[image: Recolor Artwork]